# Почему консоль выводит 4? А не 3 (setInterval+setTimout)

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout, clearinterval

Всем привет, кто может объяснить порядок выполнения кода?
Ожидалось увидеть 3, но я что-то упускаю. Хотелось бы разобраться.

```js
let i = 0;

let t  = setInterval(()=>{
     setTimeout(()=>{
         clearInterval(t);
     },3000)
     console.log(++i);
 },1000);
```

Буду благодарна за ответы:)

Comment: а почему должно было вывестись 3?

Comment: это было мое предположение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте считать.

1. Вызов setInterval запуск таймера с интервалом 1 сек.
2. Сработка t. Планировка закрытие t через 3 сек
3. Вывод на печать 1
4. Запуск второй раз Timera. Вывод на печать 2. Поскольку проходит первая секунда первого Timeout.
5. Запуск третий раз Timera. Вывод на печать 3. Проходит вторая секунда первого Timeouta.
6. Запуск четвертый раз Timera. Вывод на печать 4. Проходит третья секунда первого Timeouta.
7. Остановка t вывод первой 4-
8. Ну и три сработки оставшихся Timeoutов.

```js
let i = 0;

let t  = setInterval(()=>{
     setTimeout(()=>{
         console.log(i, "-");
         clearInterval(t);
     },3000)
     console.log(++i);
 },1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Я не учитывала что сначала планировка потом отсчет времени таймера.
Теперь все понятно

Answer (score 0):

Каждую секунду выводится инкрементированное значение `i`, спустя 3 секунды срабатывает `clearInterval` и после этого `setInterval` уже не будет вызывать функцию, которая инкрементирует значение `i`. Вы не контролируете сколько значений выведется, вы контролируете только время.

Но как вариант можно уменьшить время, через которое `setInterval` прекратит свое выполнение

```js
let i = 0;

let t  = setInterval(()=>{
     setTimeout(()=>{
         clearInterval(t);
     },2000)
     console.log(++i);
 },1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне было необходимо не получить результат, а разобраться почему именно так